# UI Observing LiveData<List<MyObject>> Shows Newly-Added and Newly-Removed Objects, but Not Updates or Changes

Tags: java, android, android-adapter, android-livedata

So I built a small list where I can add instances of MyObjects into a list. The RecyclerView I have shows correctly the newly-added instances, as well as remove what is supposed to be removed.

However, whenever I try to change the value in an existing instance, the change doesn't show, even though if I click on that item in the RecyclerView, it correctly shows the changed data. For example, if I add an instance of MyObject with a string value of "Foo", and long value of 10 (i.e. new MyObject("Foo", 10)), and edit that via an AlertDialog, and changed "Foo" to "Bar", the UI will still keep on showing "Foo", but if I click that item, its value now says, "Bar". What could be the problem here?

Here's my ActivityMain:

```
public class ActivityMain extends AppCompatActivity implements MyObjectDialog.MyObjectDialogListener {

    static MyObjectViewModel myObjectViewModel;
    public static List<MyObject> listMyObject;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        // lines for initializing views in layout

        listMyObject = new ArrayList<>();

        myObjectViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this,
                new MyObjectViewModelFactory(this.getApplication(), listMyObject)).get(MyObjectViewModel.class);

    }

    @Override
    public void saveMyObject(MyObject myObject, int indexNumberInListMyObject, boolean isNewMyObject) {

        if (isNewMyObject) {
            myObjectViewModel.addMyObject(MyObject);
        } else {
            myObjectViewModel.setMyObject(indexNumberInListMyObject, MyObject);
        }
    }
}
```

The fragment containing the RecyclerView displaying the list of MyObject instances:

```
public class MyObjectDebitFragment extends Fragment {

    private MyObjectAdapter myObjectAdapter;
    private MyViewModel myViewModel;

    private boolean isNewMyObject;
    private int indexNumberInListMyObject;

    public View onCreateView(@NonNull LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // initialize views, set adapter, etc.

        myObjectViewModel = ActivityMain.myObjectViewModel;
        myObjectViewModel.getMutableLiveDataListMyObject().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<MyObject>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<MyObject> myObjects) {
                myObjectAdapter.submitList(myObjects);
            }
        });

        myObjectAdapter.setOnItemClickListener(new MyObjectAdapter.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(myObject clickedMyObject) {
                MyObjectDialog myObjectDialog = new myObjectDialog();
                Bundle bundleClickedMyObject = new Bundle();

                bundleClickedMyObject.putInt("indexNumberInListMyObject", ActivityMain.listMyObject.indexOf(clickedMyObject));
                bundleClickedMyObject.putBoolean("isNewMyObject", false); // only pre-existing items for MyObject can be clicked
                bundleClickedMyObject.putString("stringFieldOfMyObject", clickedMyObject.getStringFieldMyObject);
                bundleClickedMyObject.putLong("longFieldOfMyObject", clickedMyObject.getLongFieldMyObject);

                myObjectDialog.setArguments(bundleClickedMyObject);
                myObjectDialog.show(requireActivity().getSupportFragmentManager(), "myObjectDialog");
            }
        });

        new ItemTouchHelper(new ItemTouchHelper.SimpleCallback(0,
                ItemTouchHelper.LEFT) {
            @Override
            public boolean onMove(@NonNull RecyclerView recyclerView, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, @NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder target) {
                return false;
            }

            @Override
            public void onSwiped(@NonNull RecyclerView.ViewHolder viewHolder, int direction) {
                    myObjectViewModel.removeMyObject(myObjectAdapter.getMyObjectAt(viewHolder.getAdapterPosition()));
            }
        }).attachToRecyclerView(recyclerViewMyObject);
    }

}
```

This is the class for MyObject:

```
public class MyObject {

    private String StringFieldForMyObject;
    private long longFieldForMyObject;

    public JournalEntryDetail(String stringFieldForMyObject, long longFieldForMyObject) {
        this.stringFieldForMyObject = stringFieldForMyObject;
        this.longFieldForMyObject = longFieldForMyObject;
    }

    public String getStringFieldForMyObject() {
        return StringFieldForMyObject;
    }

    public void setStringFieldForMyObject(String StringFieldForMyObject) {
        this.StringFieldForMyObject = StringFieldForMyObject;
    }

    public Long getLongFieldForMyObject() {
        return longFieldForMyObject;
    }

    public void setLongFieldForMyObject(String longFieldForMyObject) {
        this.longFieldForMyObject = longFieldForMyObject;
    }
}
```

Here's how I wrote my ViewModel

```
public class MyViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {

  private MutableLiveData<List<MyObject>> mutableLiveDataListMyObject;
  private List<MyObject> listMyObject;

  public MyViewModel(@NonNull Application application, List<MyObject> paramListMyObject) {
    super(application);
    if (mutableLiveDataListMyObject == null){
      mutableLiveDataListMyObject = new MutableLiveData<>();
      listMyObject = paramList;
      mutableLiveDataListMyObject.setValue(paramListMyObject);
    }
  }

  public void addMyObject (MyObject myObject) {
    listMyObject.add(myObject);
  }

  public void setMyObject (int indexPosition, MyObject myObject) {
    listMyObject.set(indexPosition, myObject);
  }

  public void removeMyObject(MyObject myObject) {
    listMyObject.remove(myObject);
  }

  public LiveData<List<MyObject>> getMutableLiveDataListMyObject() {
    return mutableLiveDataListMyObject;
  }
}
```

Factory class for MyViewModel

```
public class MyViewModelFactory extends ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory {

    private Application application;
    private List<MyObject> listMyObject;

    public MyViewModelFactory(Application paramApplication, List<MyObject> paramListMyObject) {
        super(paramApplication);
        application = paramApplication;
        listMyObject = paramListMyObject;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public <T extends ViewModel> T create(@NonNull Class<T> modelClass) {
        if (modelClass == MyViewModel.class) {
            return (T) new MyViewModel(application, listMyObject);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

Dialog for editing or adding a new instance of MyObject

```
public class MyObjectDialog extends DialogFragment {

    private MyObjectDialogListener MyObjectDialogListener;

    private boolean isNewMyObject;
    private int indexNumberInListMyObject;
    private String stringFieldOfMyObject;
    private long longFieldOfMyObject;

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public Dialog onCreateDialog(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreateDialog(savedInstanceState);

        AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(requireActivity());

    // lines for initializing views

        if (getArguments() != null) {
        isNewMyObject = getArguments().getBoolean("isNewMyObject", true)
        indexNumberInListMyObject = getArguments().getInt("indexNumberInListMyObject", 0);
        stringFieldOfMyObject = getArguments().getString("stringFieldOfMyObject");
        longFieldOfMyObject = getArguments().getString("longFieldOfMyObject", 0);

                editTextStringFieldOfMyObject.setText(stringFieldOfMyObject);
                editTextLongFieldOfMyObject.setText(String.valueOf(longFieldOfMyObject));
        }

    

        alertDialogBuilder.setView(itemView)
                .setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                        // do nothing
                    }
                })
                .setPositiveButton("Save", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

                        stringFieldOfMyObject = editTextStringFieldOfMyObject.getText().toString();
                        longFieldOfMyObject = Long.parseLong(editTextLongFieldOfMyObject.getText().toString());

                        MyObject myObject = new MyObject(stringValue, longValue);

                        MyObjectDialogListener.saveMyObject(myObject, indexNumberInListMyObject, isNewMyObject);
                    }
                });

        return alertDialogBuilder.create();
    }

    @Override
    public void onAttach(@NonNull Context context) {
        super.onAttach(context);
        try {
            MyObjectDialogListener = (MyObjectDialogListener) context;
        } catch (ClassCastException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new ClassCastException(context.toString() +
                    "Must implement MyObjectDialogListener");
        }
    }

    public interface MyObjectDialogListener {
        void saveMyObject(MyObject myObject, int indexInListMyObject, boolean isNewMyObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would you please provide me with information about your layouts? Specifically those include fragments.

Comment: I added a setValue() for each method where I added, changed, or removed an item in the list for the ViewModel class, and added a notifyDataSetChanged() in the overriding of OnChanged in the observer of the viewModel instance.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this adding in the ViewModel class the line mutableLiveDataListMyObject.setValue(listMyObject):

```
  public void addMyObject (MyObject myObject) {
    listMyObject.add(myObject);
    mutableLiveDataListMyObject.setValue(listMyObject);
  }

  public void setMyObject (int indexPosition, MyObject myObject) {
    listMyObject.set(indexPosition, myObject);
    mutableLiveDataListMyObject.setValue(listMyObject);
  }

  public void removeMyObject(MyObject myObject) {
    listMyObject.remove(myObject);
    mutableLiveDataListMyObject.setValue(listMyObject);
  }
```

and on the observer implementation for the ViewModel instance, I added myObjectAdapeter.notifyDataSetChanged():

```
myObjectViewModel.getMutableLiveDataListMyObject().observe(getViewLifecycleOwner(), new Observer<List<MyObject>>() {
            @Override
            public void onChanged(List<MyObject> myObjects) {
                myObjectAdapter.submitList(myObjects);
                myObjectAdapeter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
```

I'm yet to fully understand the difference why I had to this when I used MutableLiveData, because when I used Room, I didn't have to do either of these.